# Map only a particular object based on ID in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an array of objects, which looks like:

```
const cartItems = [
  {
    id: 1,
    new1: "Hello",
    new2: "New hello"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    new1: "Hello",
    new2: "New hello"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    new1: "Hello",
    new2: "New hello"
  }
];
```

I am currently using this array of objects to map over all items like this:

```
cartItems.map(product => (
    <React.Fragment key={product.id}>
        <p>{product.new1}</p>
    </React.Fragment>
));
```

This loops over all the products, but I would like to have this code limited to one particular product. Like with ID=3 or whatever I supply.

```
cartItems.find(product => product.id === 3)
```

The above code helps me find it, but I cannot map over it to loop and write some React UI on it. Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: put the found item in a variable? and then use that data like you would any other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `find()` function only returns a single item and not an array of items. If you would like to iterate you need an array with an single item. This can be done using the `filter()` function.

```
cartItems.filter(product => product.id === 3).map(item => (
  // Your React stuff
))
```

as alterative you can access the properties directly when using the `find()` function.

```
{const singleCardItem = cartItems.find(product => product.id === 3)}
<p>singleCardItem.new1</p>
```

[`find()` Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

[`filter()` Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the found item into its own variable and then use that?

```
const cartItems = [
  {
    id: 1,
    new1: "Hello",
    new2: "New hello"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    new1: "Hello",
    new2: "New hello"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    new1: "Hello",
    new2: "New hello"
  }
];

const { new1 } = cartItems.find(product => product.id === 3);

return <p>{new1}</p>;
```

This also removes the need for a key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()`. It will return an array and you can `map` it as in question.

```
{cartItems.filter(product => product.id === 3).map(product => (
    <React.Fragment key={product.id}>
        <p>{product.new1}</p>
    </React.Fragment>
));}
```

As suggested by `evolutionxbox` in the comment, it'll be better to extract in a variable and use it in `render`.

Answer (score 0):

That's a complete solution in React.
You need to filter and after map on array of results.

```
export default function App() {
  const cartItems = [
    {
      id: 1,
      new1: "Hello",
      new2: "New hello"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      new1: "Hello",
      new2: "New hello"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      new1: "Hello",
      new2: "New hello"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {cartItems
        .filter(product => product.id === 3)
        .map(product_map => <p>{product_map.id}</p>)}
    </div>
)}
```